# $j^{th}$-order tangential differential operator on the hypersphere with smooth coefficients

Tags: derivatives, differential-geometry, spherical-coordinates

What does this look like?  The context is the following: $f(\mathbf x)$ is a function defined on the unit hypersphere $S^{n-1} = \{ \mathbf x\in\mathbb R^n : |\mathbf x| = 1 \}$ where $|\cdot|$ is the Euclidean norm. $D_{\mathbf x}^j$ is defined as a "$j^{th}$-order tangential differential operator on $S^{n-1}$ with smooth coefficients".

I understand this generalizes the concept of differential to the hypersphere, but say $f(x,y) = \sqrt{x^4 + y^4}$, how do I calculate $D_{\mathbf x}^j f$ ?

Thanks,
p.

Comment: You took an example of an $f$. What's an example of $D^j_{\mathbf x}$?

Comment: @TedShifrin Well... that's what I'm asking?  As a function of R^n I can easily calculate $df = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} dx + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} dy$, but I don't know how to deal with the contraint $x^2+y^2=1$ to define $D_{\mathbf x}^j$.  Are you saying there are many ways to define it?